# Django Symlink Missing (how to install it using pip)

Tags: python, django, symlink

Im Trying to use Symlink in my Django Project:

```
os.symlink(static_file_path, media_file_path)
```

But what i get in result is: Undefined variable from import: symlink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`os.symlink`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.symlink) is part of the `os` package, which is included with Python. You don't have to install it.

```
import os
os.symlink(source, link_name)
```

Comment: Well its same at me, but i still get this error - Undefined variable from import: symlink . Maybe im using old version of python ?

Comment: Are you using Windows? The docs say that symlink doesn't work with Windows in Python 2.

Comment: my god, why is that ? yes im using windows python 2.7, maybe its because its not installed there ?

Comment: thx man anyway, i solved this using that post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260149/os-symlink-support-in-windows ! thx for hint.

Comment: It has not always been possible to add symlinks in Windows, so when `os.symlink` was added for Windows, it was added to Python 3 only. Python 2.7  was the last Python 2 release in 2010. There are bug fixes and security fixes, but no new features are added to Python 2 since then.