# Error: module' object has no attribute 'symlink

Tags: python, python-2.7, ansible

I am installing Ansible using Python2.7 but I am having an error upon installation.

Here are my steps and I am using Windows 10 64 bit

1. Install Python 2.7
2. Go to command line and go to directory **C:\Python27\Scripts**
3. Type command **pip install ansible**

Error

```
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\dave\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-_tn3so\\ansible\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\dave\appdata\local\temp\pip-ltscus-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\dave\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-_tn3so\ansible\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is clearly stated in [the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#control-machine-requirements), Windows is not supported for use as a control machine. Even if you got it to install, the next problem you'd have is trying to convince it to use a sane ssh client, of which PuTTY is not one.

I am sure you can use the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) to gain access to a reasonable operating system inside the unreasonable one

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
import os.path
import platform
import subprocess

def _symlink(source, link_name):
    # If we are already in a version of python that supports symlinks then
    # just use the os module, otherwise fall back on ctypes.  It requires
    # administrator privileges to run or the correct group policy to be set.
    # This implementation is taken from
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260149/os-symlink-support-in-windows
    if callable(getattr(os, "symlink", None)):
        os.symlink(source, link_name)
    elif "Windows-10" in platform.platform():
        # Starting with Windows 10 Insiders build 14972, symlinks can be
        # created without needing to elevate the console as administrator.
        # https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/#joC5tFKhdXs2gGml.97
        subprocess.check_output("mklink %s %s" % (link_name, source), shell=True)
    else:
        import ctypes
        csl = ctypes.windll.kernel32.CreateSymbolicLinkW
        csl.argtypes = (ctypes.c_wchar_p, ctypes.c_wchar_p, ctypes.c_uint32)
        csl.restype = ctypes.c_ubyte
        flags = 1 if os.path.isdir(source) else 0
        if csl(link_name, source, flags) == 0:
            raise ctypes.WinError()
```