# Recursively searching for files in Python

Tags: python, search, recursion

I am trying to write code that uses a recursive function to search for files in a directory, and returns the path to the file that matches the search term. However, I keep getting this error when I use "../.." as the path name "PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: '../..\AppData\Local\Application Data'".

```
import os
def main():

pathname=input('Please enter path name: ')
filenameinput=input('Please enter file name: ')

def disk_usage(path):

    if os.path.isdir(path):
        for filename in os.listdir(path):
            childpath = os.path.join(path, filename)
            if os.path.isdir(childpath):
                disk_usage(childpath)
            else:
                if childpath.endswith(filenameinput):
                    print(childpath)
#return 
disk_usage(pathname)
main()
```

I should not need to use `os.walk()` for this. I have it working but it returns several paths ending in the filename I specified and then returns the WinError 5 thing.

Comment: "I get back errors" - always a classic.  Why not tell us what the errors are?

Comment: Didn't you ask this question earlier, then delete it when I asked you why you're not just using `os.walk`?

Comment: [be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839/the-new-new-be-nice-policy-code-of-conduct-updated-with-your-feedback) y'all. these counterquestions seem a little meanspirited.

Comment: @plarke: What's mean-spirited about asking someone whether they've already asked a question? If this is the same person, there were a number of useful comments on that question. If it's a different person, he has exactly the same question as someone else, whose question got a number of useful comments. Either way, why wouldn't that information be worth knowing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a permission error because `Application Data` is not a real folder in Windows 7+, it's a "junction" (symlink in Unix-speak) pointing to `C:\Program Files`. It only exists for backwards compatibility.

You have two options:

1. You can read the junction with some Windows-specific native code, through `win32file`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447575/symlinks-on-windows/7924557#7924557) SO answer.
2. You can catch the permission error, and ignore it (maybe print a warning message). This is probably the better option unless you *really* need to read this folder.