# Python symbolic links on windows do not show up

Tags: python, ctypes, symlink

I have seen [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447575/symlinks-on-windows) about how to create symbolic links on Windows using Python (I am on Win 7). However the links does not show up in the system for some reason even though the call claim success. Am I missing something obvious ?

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> kdll = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll")
>>> kdll.CreateSymbolicLinkA("C:\\testlink", "C:\\existing_dir", 1)
1
>>> ctypes.WinError()
WindowsError(0, 'The operation completed successfully.')
>>> kdll.CreateSymbolicLinkA("C:\\testlink", "C:\\existing_dir", 1)
0
>>> ctypes.WinError()
WindowsError(0, 'Cannot create a file when that file already exists.')
>>> os.path.exists("C:\\testlink")
False
>>> os.path.islink("C:\\testlink")
False
```

Why does the calls to the windows api think that that the link was created when python can't see it with os.path.exist ? And neither can I see the link in the file explorer or using `dir` in cmd on the Windows box. So where did the link go ?

Comment: if the link is broken, then it is not exists, but islink is true, because the file is there. and there is os.symlink function, just for that

Comment: os.path.islink also reports False. I am on Python 2.7, and os.symlink say it's available only on Unix.

Comment: However I see I can work around this by instead using subprocess and calling mklink directly from the shell like `call(['mklink', 'C:\\testlink', 'C:\\existing_dir'], shell=True)`. Still that does not explain why I see the behavior above - so I am still curious.

Comment: It should work if you have `SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege`, and it says that it did work. Did you try creating the link in another directory, such as `C:\Temp`? If you're using 32-bit Python, maybe it was created in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\VirtualStore`.

Comment: sorry, my bad. I didn't realize python2 does not support symlink on windows. It does support on python3 though. https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=symlink#os.symlink

Comment: @eryksun I see nothing VirtualStore. I ran the above commands with admin rights, without it the first link command fails.

Comment: Your `mklink` command creates a broken link. You need `mklink /d` to link to a directory. Trying to open a file as a directory fails. This is checked in the `NtOpenFile` system call before the path is reparsed to follow the symbolic link, so the actual link itself needs to be created as a directory. That's why your `CreateSymbolicLink` call uses the flag `SYMBOLIC_LINK_FLAG_DIRECTORY` (1).

Comment: That was a typo in my comment - the workaround worked, but not the original approach.