# Python os.listDir throws "WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied:" on some folders

Tags: python, windows, file, operating-system

Basically I have a FileExplorer class written in Python 2.6. It works great, I can navigate through drives, folders, etc.
However, when I get to a specific folder *'C:\Documents and Settings/*.*'*, os.listdir, on which my script is based, throws this error:

**WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Documents and Settings/*.*'**

Why is that? Is it because this folder is read-only? Or is it something Windows is protecting and my script cannot access?!

Here is the offending code(line 3):

```
def listChildDirs(self):
    list = []
    for item in os.listdir(self.path):
        if item!=None and\
            os.path.isdir(os.path.join(self.path, item)):
            print item
            list.append(item)
        #endif
    #endfor
    return list
```

Comment: Which version of Windows? In Vista and later, C:\Documents and Settings is a junction, not a real directory.

Comment: It is Windows 7, sorry forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Vista and later, C:\Documents and Settings is a junction, not a real directory.

You can't even do a straight `dir` in it.

```
C:\Windows\System32>dir "c:\Documents and Settings"
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 762E-5F95

 Directory of c:\Documents and Settings

File Not Found
```

Sadly, using `os.path.isdir()`, it will return `True`

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.isdir(r'C:\Documents and Settings')
True
```

You could have a look at these answers for dealing with symlinks in Windows.

- [Create NTFS junction in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143260/create-ntfs-junction-point-in-python)
- [Symlinks in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447575/symlinks-on-windows/7924557#7924557)

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. This is a good use for exception handling.

Comment: Thank you very much, this explains a lot. @Mike, yes, exactly how I'm thinking of working around it - catch the exception.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a permissions setting for directory access, or even that the directory's not there. You can either run your script as administrator (ie access to everything) or try something like this:

```
def listChildDirs(self):
    list = []
    if not os.path.isdir(self.path):
        print "%s is not a real directory!" % self.path
        return list
    try:
        for item in os.listdir(self.path):
            if item!=None and\
                os.path.isdir(os.path.join(self.path, item)):
                print item
                list.append(item)
            #endif
        #endfor
    except WindowsError:
        print "Oops - we're not allowed to list %s" % self.path
    return list
```

By the way, have you heard of [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)? It looks like it might be a short cut for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Wouldn't os.walk just recursively list all the directory's children, grandchildren, grand-grand children, etc? I want to just show the children.

Comment: You could stop walking by returning in the `for` loop