# Python's _winapi module

Tags: python, winapi, cpython

I was trying to write some python code that requires calls to native `WINAPI` functions. At first I came across the `pypiwin32` package. Then, somewhere on the internet I saw someone using the `_winapi` module. I found no proper documentation for this module, only [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_winapi.c) link to `cpython`'s GitHub page. 
Is this a `cpython`-specific module? That is, is it not guaranteed that other implementations have this module? 

Do I need the `pypiwin32` package if the functions I need are already implemented in the `_winapi` module?

Comment: I don't have much information to provide, but I did want to clarify that yes this is a native module and afaik is included with all standard versions of python. Fwiw, my experience with PyWin32 has always been bad on numerous occasions as the installation never wants to detect it's binary modules after the initial run, if at all. So yeah, I personally have no need for PyWin32. Although, documentation for `_winapi` seems to be getting increasingly difficult to find, let alone documentation for the ctypes trickery with `windll.kernel32` or `windll.user32` and such.

Comment: Afraid I can't add much, but for me on Windows 10, python 2.7.15 `import _winapi` fails with `ImportError`, whereas on python 3.6.6 it works fine (both are standard cpython installs from python.org). Is this new in python 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems `_winapi` is specific to CPython and was added in python 3.3 under [Issue 11750](https://bugs.python.org/issue11750).

See `Modules/_winapi.c` which was added by [this commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/23bba4ca)

This fits with the following observed behaviour:

- python 2.x - 3.2 `import _winapi` fails with `ImportError`
- python 3.3+ `import _winapi` works fine

Relying upon `_winapi` is a bad idea as it's undocumented and CPython-specific.

Comment: And there isnt much in it, see available [functions](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f3a27d11101a/Modules/_winapi.c#l1198). Nothing you wouldn't get elsewhere.